# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OPPCheckoutProvider", referenced from

Tags: ios, flutter, architecture

[image: architecture not found.]

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OPPCheckoutProvider", referenced from: objc-class-ref in FlutterPeachpayPlugin.o "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OPPCheckoutSettings", referenced from: objc-class-ref in FlutterPeachpayPlugin.o "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OPPPaymentProvider", referenced from: objc-class-ref in FlutterPeachpayPlugin.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)